# gcc cannot compile C files using mpi.h

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, centos7

I just received a message where someone could not compile a C file.
When they try to compile, it's getting the following error.

```
$ gcc mpi01.c 
mpi01.c:1:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
#include <mpi.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.
$
```

I'm sure the C code is present so it must be a problem with the installation, but `mpi.h` is there.

```
/opt/mpss/3.6/sysroots/k1om-mpss-linux/usr/src/kernel/drivers/message/fusion/lsi/mpi.h
/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/mpi.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/mpi.h
```

Does someone know what I could do?

The system is running Centos7.

Edit 1:

To respond to the answers. It is not my code that I am trying to compile.  What I did to "ensure" everything is in place for C compiling:

```
yum install gcc openmpi kernel-devel kernel-headers openmpi-devel
```

I do not know if I am allowed to post the code, but the following headers are included in the code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The compiler command line was the following:

```
vim mpi01.c 
module load mpi
gcc -o mpi01 mpi01.c
```

Resulting in the error above.

Comment: It looks like you need to make sure the compiler command line includes `-I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64` (and when it comes to linking, you may have to specify a directory `-L/usr/lib/openmpi-x86_64` or something — where the `libmpi.so` file is found).

Comment: gcc -o -I  /usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/mpi.h  mpi01.c

Comment: Not like that - `gcc -I /usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 -o mpi01 mpi01.c -lmpi` (where the `-lmpi` picks up the OpenMPI library, with luck; without luck, you'll need to find it and specify `-L/directory/containing/openmpi-library`.  Note that both `-I` and `-L` expect a directory, not a file name.  The space between the `-I` or `-L` and the directory is optional — I tend to use the attached notation out of many, many years habit.

Comment: Using `mpicc` (instead of `gcc`) may also work for you. Generally `mpicc` will act as a thin wrapper around your default compiler supplying the correct parameters as Jonathan et all have mentioned.

Comment: I included the path now in the actual file #include </usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/mpi.h>
Now it is trying to compile, still with errors about the code. But does not contain the actual system. It also seems like mpicc is not installed, because, the command cannot be found.

Comment: Only ever edit an absolute pathname into the source code as a temporary measure, and as a last resource. If you don't have the support necessary to compile MPI programs, then MPI programs won't compile.  I'm not familiar enough with OpenMPI to be able to give you definitive pointers, but you need to become familiar with your package manager and how to list and install MPI packages.  If you need `mpicc`, then you need to find out what to install and get it installed.  The names are not standard across Linux distributions; what works on Debian won't work on RedHat or Ubuntu, etc.

Comment: I had an old Centos5 distro laying around. I discovered that you may actually have to select the MPI implementation you want to use. It can be set on a user or system basis with the command `mpi-selector-menu` . Once you make the change then close the shell you are logged in with and log in again. After selecting openmpi here, `mpicc` among all the other tools became available. In my case i made it system wide so it would be set for all users, but you can set it for specific users as well.

Comment: To your edit... if it is not your code that you are compiling, your question is most appropriately directed to whomever you got the code from.  Setting up a compilation environment is a lot more than yum installing some set of packages- even worse to guess which packages to install based on error messages.  Does the project use auto-conf?  What is its list of dependencies?